# service firestore is not available

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to connect to my firestore using plain javascript. (I wanna get up to speed and running for now)

index.js:

```
import app from './firebase.js'
import { getFirestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-firestore.js'
const db = getFirestore(app)
```

However, this throws an error: `Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available`

firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js";
 
  const firebaseConfig = {
    // configs
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  let app
  export default app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Then I import the script in my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
<script type="module" src="index.html"></script>
```

**Note**: I can read and write to the firestore using firebase web interface.

Comment: You cannot import a module from remote url, so `import { something } from 'https://...';` won't work and that's why is throwing an error.

Comment: Not so sure that's the cause because `firebase.js` was loading fine.

Comment: Go to firebase console and add new web app. They generate the code for you.

Answer (score 3):

Using npm, but got the same error message.
Restarted terminal & uninstalled and reinstall firebase, then worked...not sure which one that did it though.

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to use plain js (without bundlers like webpack), you would need to put your JS code into `script` tag like so:

```html
<script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js";
  
  const firebaseConfig = { ... };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

Otherwise, if you want to use it like you intended to do so, you would need to:

- install a firebase package
- a module bundler (e.g. webpack) to bundle the files for you

Comment: Checkout my updated question I'm already adding `type="module"`

Comment: `<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>` not `src="index.html"` but I guess you have that already since firestore is working properly?

Comment: I faced the same issue. I just downgraded for testing and it worked. In this js file:  import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, getDoc, DocumentSnapshot, query, where, limit} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-firestore.js';

Comment: Really? 9.0.0 solves the issue? I don't have bandwidth to go back to it as I've moved my project to webpack, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your firestore version 9.0.0 to 9.4.0 and it work fine

```js
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-firestore.js";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your import link

```
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js";
```

to

```
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js";
```

just **update** the firebase version from **9.0.0 to 9.0.1**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error which I corrected by using cdks with the same version. In my case I used the version (9.20.0)

```
"https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js" 
"https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-firestore.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had my initial imports as:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-firestore.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-analytics.js";
```

So I changed the version of my firestore from 9.1.1 to 9.21.0