# Getting auth after initializing app not working - app/no-app (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

Pretty simple really - even though I have initalized my app, I can't get auth (`getAuth()`). I'm building a Node module for React/Gatsby apps.

I've imported Firebase:

```
import { initializeApp } from '@firebase/app'
import * as firebaseAuth from '@firebase/auth'
```

I initialize the app in componentDidMount in the main component, then get auth, like this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
        // my firebase app config
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = firebaseAuth.getAuth()
```

But on getting auth (`getAuth()`), I get an error:
[image: firebase app/no-app error]

... which seems weird since I *just* initialized the app.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to pass the app to getAuth. `FirebaseAuth GetAuth(
  FirebaseApp app
)` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-auth#class_firebase_1_1_auth_1_1_firebase_auth_1afcf28ace32a24ce2b1a360d39364dcbc

Comment: I believe I might have tried this before, but will sure give it another go

Comment: @Will ok, (soz for taking ages), while that did fix one error (supposedly), it is now giving me a 'Component auth has not been registered yet' error (no error code).

Comment: [This fella](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4819) had that problem and nobody could reproduce it. I'd copy the example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup . It looks like your example code is correct but it's hard to tell with small snippets. The examples in these docs https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web might be helpful.

Comment: This article might be helpful: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-setup-firebase-authentication-with-react-in-5-minutes-maybe-10-bb8bb53e8834

Comment: update: when i try getting the firestore (`getFirestore(app)`), i am thrown this error, again no code - 'Service firestore is not available'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033048/service-firestore-is-not-available

Comment: no luck i'm afraid